# hello i want to ask about my personal global planner in ROS_Noetic

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-noetic

i set the my personal global planner in ros_noetic
my name is chang, so i make my own planner which named changs_planner
it is package name in ros, and in src folder i make two file, changs_planner.cpp, changs_planner.h
this is changs_planner.cpp

```
#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>
#include "changs_planner.h"
#include <tf/tf.h>


PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(changs_planner::CarrotPlanner, 
nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner)
namespace changs_planner {

CarrotPlanner::CarrotPlanner ()
: costmap_ros_(NULL), initialized_(false){}


CarrotPlanner::CarrotPlanner(std::string name, 
costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS* costmap_ros)
: costmap_ros_(NULL), initialized_(false){
initialize(name, costmap_ros);
}


void CarrotPlanner::initialize(std::string name, 
costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS* costmap_ros){
    if(!initialized_){
      costmap_ros_ = costmap_ros;
      costmap_ = costmap_ros_->getCostmap();

      ros::NodeHandle private_nh("~/" + name);
      private_nh.param("step_size", step_size_, costmap_- >getResolution());
  private_nh.param("min_dist_from_robot", min_dist_from_robot_, 0.10);
  world_model_ = new base_local_planner::CostmapModel(*costmap_); 

  initialized_ = true;
}
else
  ROS_WARN("This planner has already been initialized... doing nothing");
  }

double CarrotPlanner::footprintCost(double x_i, double y_i, double theta_i){
if(!initialized_){
  ROS_ERROR("The planner has not been initialized, please call initialize() to use the planner");
  return -1.0;
}

std::vector<geometry_msgs::Point> footprint = costmap_ros_->getRobotFootprint();
//if we have no footprint... do nothing
if(footprint.size() < 3)
  return -1.0;

//check if the footprint is legal
double footprint_cost = world_model_->footprintCost(x_i, y_i, theta_i, footprint);
return footprint_cost;
}


bool CarrotPlanner::makePlan(const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& start, 
  const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& goal, std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>& plan){
if(!initialized_){
  ROS_ERROR("The planner has not been initialized, please call initialize() to use the planner");
  return false;
}
ROS_DEBUG("Got a start: %.2f, %.2f, and a goal: %.2f, %.2f", start.pose.position.x, start.pose.position.y, goal.pose.position.x, goal.pose.position.y);

plan.clear();
costmap_ = costmap_ros_->getCostmap();

if(goal.header.frame_id != costmap_ros_->getGlobalFrameID()){
  ROS_ERROR("This planner as configured will only accept goals in the %s frame, but a goal was sent in the %s frame.", 
      costmap_ros_->getGlobalFrameID().c_str(), goal.header.frame_id.c_str());
  return false;
}

tf::Stamped<tf::Pose> goal_tf;
tf::Stamped<tf::Pose> start_tf;

poseStampedMsgToTF(goal,goal_tf);
poseStampedMsgToTF(start,start_tf);

double useless_pitch, useless_roll, goal_yaw, start_yaw;
start_tf.getBasis().getEulerYPR(start_yaw, useless_pitch, useless_roll);
goal_tf.getBasis().getEulerYPR(goal_yaw, useless_pitch, useless_roll);

//we want to step back along the vector created by the robot's position and the goal pose until we find a legal cell
double goal_x = goal.pose.position.x;
double goal_y = goal.pose.position.y;
double start_x = start.pose.position.x;
double start_y = start.pose.position.y;

double diff_x = goal_x - start_x;
double diff_y = goal_y - start_y;
double diff_yaw = angles::normalize_angle(goal_yaw-start_yaw);

double target_x = goal_x;
double target_y = goal_y;
double target_yaw = goal_yaw;

bool done = false;
double scale = 1.0;
double dScale = 0.01;

while(!done)
 {
   if(scale < 0)
   {
    target_x = start_x;
    target_y = start_y;
    target_yaw = start_yaw;
    ROS_WARN("The carrot planner could not find a valid plan for this goal");
    break;
  }
  target_x = start_x + scale * diff_x;
  target_y = start_y + scale * diff_y;
  target_yaw = angles::normalize_angle(start_yaw + scale * diff_yaw);
  
  double footprint_cost = footprintCost(target_x, target_y, target_yaw);
  if(footprint_cost >= 0)
  {
      done = true;
  }
  scale -=dScale;
}

plan.push_back(start);
geometry_msgs::PoseStamped new_goal = goal;
tf::Quaternion goal_quat = tf::createQuaternionFromYaw(target_yaw);

new_goal.pose.position.x = target_x;
new_goal.pose.position.y = target_y;

new_goal.pose.orientation.x = goal_quat.x();
new_goal.pose.orientation.y = goal_quat.y();
new_goal.pose.orientation.z = goal_quat.z();
new_goal.pose.orientation.w = goal_quat.w();

plan.push_back(new_goal);
return (done);
}

};
```

and this is changs_planner.h

```
#ifndef CARROT_PLANNER_H_1
#define CARROT_PLANNER_H_1
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <costmap_2d/costmap_2d_ros.h>
#include <costmap_2d/costmap_2d.h>
#include <nav_core/base_global_planner.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/PoseStamped.h>
#include <angles/angles.h>
#include <tf/tf.h>
#include <tf/transform_datatypes.h>
#include <base_local_planner/world_model.h>
#include <base_local_planner/costmap_model.h>
namespace changs_planner{
  class CarrotPlanner : public nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner {
    public:
  CarrotPlanner();
  CarrotPlanner(std::string name, costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS* costmap_ros);
  void initialize(std::string name, costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS* costmap_ros);
  bool makePlan(const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& start, 
      const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& goal, std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>& plan);

private:
  costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS* costmap_ros_;
  double step_size_, min_dist_from_robot_;
  costmap_2d::Costmap2D* costmap_;
  base_local_planner::WorldModel* world_model_; 

  double footprintCost(double x_i, double y_i, double theta_i);

  bool initialized_;
  };
};  
#endif
```

and then this is changs_planner_plugin.xml

```
<library path="lib/libchangs_planner_lib">
  <class name="changs_planner/CarrotPlanner" 
type="changs_planner::CarrotPlanner" 
base_class_type="nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner">
    <description></description>
  </class>
</library>
```

this is cmake

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  base_local_planner
  costmap_2d
  geometry_msgs
  nav_msgs
  nav_core
  pluginlib
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
  tf
)


find_package(PCL REQUIRED)





catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES changs_planner
  CATKIN_DEPENDS base_local_planner costmap_2d geometry_msgs nav_msgs pluginlib roscpp sensor_msgs std_msgs tf
  DEPENDS system_lib
  LIBRARIES changs_planner_lib
)


include_directories(
# include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${TF_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)


add_library(changs_planner_lib src/changs_planner.cpp)
target_link_libraries(changs_planner_lib ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

and package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="2">
  <name>changs_planner</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The changs_planner package</description>

  <!-- One maintainer tag required, multiple allowed, one person per tag -->
  <!-- Example:  -->
  <!-- <maintainer email="jane.doe@example.com">Jane Doe</maintainer> -->
  <maintainer email="chang@todo.todo">chang</maintainer>


  <!-- One license tag required, multiple allowed, one license per tag -->
  <!-- Commonly used license strings: -->
  <!--   BSD, MIT, Boost Software License, GPLv2, GPLv3, LGPLv2.1, LGPLv3 -->
  <license>TODO</license>


  <!-- Url tags are optional, but multiple are allowed, one per tag -->
  <!-- Optional attribute type can be: website, bugtracker, or repository -->
  <!-- Example: -->
  <!-- <url type="website">http://wiki.ros.org/changs_planner</url> -->


  <!-- Author tags are optional, multiple are allowed, one per tag -->
  <!-- Authors do not have to be maintainers, but could be -->
  <!-- Example: -->
  <!-- <author email="jane.doe@example.com">Jane Doe</author> -->


  <!-- The *depend tags are used to specify dependencies -->
  <!-- Dependencies can be catkin packages or system dependencies -->
  <!-- Examples: -->
  <!-- Use depend as a shortcut for packages that are both build and exec dependencies -->
  <!--   <depend>roscpp</depend> -->
  <!--   Note that this is equivalent to the following: -->
  <!--   <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend> -->
  <!--   <exec_depend>roscpp</exec_depend> -->
  <!-- Use build_depend for packages you need at compile time: -->
  <!--   <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend> -->
  <!-- Use build_export_depend for packages you need in order to build against this package: -->
  <!--   
  <build_export_depend>message_generation</build_export_depend> -->
  <!-- Use buildtool_depend for build tool packages: -->
  <!--   <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend> -->
  <!-- Use exec_depend for packages you need at runtime: -->
  <!--   <exec_depend>message_runtime</exec_depend> -->
  <!-- Use test_depend for packages you need only for testing: -->
  <!--   <test_depend>gtest</test_depend> --> 
  <!-- Use doc_depend for packages you need only for building 
documentation: -->
  <!--   <doc_depend>doxygen</doc_depend> -->
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roslaunch</build_depend>
  <build_depend>base_local_planner</build_depend>
  <build_depend>costmap_2d</build_depend>
  <build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>nav_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>pluginlib</build_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>sensor_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>tf</build_depend>
  <build_depend>nav_core</build_depend>
  <build_depend>move_base</build_depend>
  <build_export_depend>base_local_planner</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>costmap_2d</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>geometry_msgs</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>nav_msgs</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>pluginlib</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>roscpp</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>sensor_msgs</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>std_msgs</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>tf</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>nav_core</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>move_base</build_export_depend>
  <exec_depend>base_local_planner</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>costmap_2d</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>geometry_msgs</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>nav_msgs</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>pluginlib</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>roscpp</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>sensor_msgs</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>tf</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>nav_core</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>move_base</exec_depend>


  <!-- The export tag contains other, unspecified, tags -->
  <export>
    <!-- Other tools can request additional information be placed here -->
    <nav_core plugin="${prefix}/changs_planner_plugin.xml" />
  </export>
 </package>
```

and finally, i set the move_base.launch like this

```
<launch>
<!-- Arguments -->
<arg name="model" default="$(env TURTLEBOT3_MODEL)" doc="model type [burger, waffle, waffle_pi]"/>
<arg name="cmd_vel_topic" default="/cmd_vel" />
<arg name="odom_topic" default="odom" />
<arg name="move_forward_only" default="false"/>

<!-- move_base -->
<node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
<param name="base_global_planner" value="changs_planner/CarrotPlanner" />
<param name="base_local_planner" value="dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS" />
<rosparam file="$(find 
turtlebot3_navigation)/param/costmap_common_params_$(arg model).yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
<rosparam file="$(find 
turtlebot3_navigation)/param/costmap_common_params_$(arg model).yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
<rosparam file="$(find 
turtlebot3_navigation)/param/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
<rosparam file="$(find 
turtlebot3_navigation)/param/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
<rosparam file="$(find 
 turtlebot3_navigation)/param/move_base_params.yaml" command="load" />
<rosparam file="$(find t 
turtlebot3_navigation)/param/dwa_local_planner_params_$(arg model).yaml" command="load" />
    <remap from="cmd_vel" to="$(arg cmd_vel_topic)"/>
    <remap from="odom" to="$(arg odom_topic)"/>
    <param name="DWAPlannerROS/min_vel_x" value="0.0" if="$(arg 
move_forward_only)" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

and after that, i did catkin_make, its good!
and then
roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_world.launch and it also work well
after that
roslaunch turtlebot3_navigation turtlebot3_navigation.launch, there is no problem but in weird part is this.
this is changs_planner_plugin.xml

[image]
there is no global planner which called changs_planner. only DWAPlannerRos which is i set as local planner.

Comment: please do not post pictures of text ... post the text instead, and format it as code ... only the last picture is unavoidable ... a picture cannot be easily copied and tested

Comment: @jsotola hello, jsotola! im really sorry to my rude. i changed all the picture to code. thank you for your advise and really sorry that make you uncomfortable

Comment: please do not apologize ... it has nothing to do with comfort ... the question is easier to answer of the code can be copied and tested ... that way more people will seriously look at your question

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be here:

```xml
<!-- move_base -->
<node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <param name="base_global_planner" value="changs_planner/CarrotPlanner" />
    <param name="base_local_planner" value="dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/param/costmap_common_params_$(arg model).yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap"/>
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/param/costmap_common_params_$(arg model).yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/param/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/param/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/param/move_base_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/param/dwa_local_planner_params_$(arg model).yaml" command="load" />
    <remap from="cmd_vel" to="$(arg cmd_vel_topic)"/>
    <remap from="odom" to="$(arg odom_topic)"/>
    <param name="DWAPlannerROS/min_vel_x" value="0.0" if="$(arg move_forward_only)" />
</node>
```

Observe that you're setting the parameters `base_global_parameter` and `base_local_planner`, which is so far, so good. But then you're calling `rosparam` to load new parameters! I bet if you check the local and global planner parameters (which you can do using the `rosparam` command line tool), you'll find that `move_base` is never being asked to load your planner.

Try copying the turtlebot_navigation parameter files to create your own versions, and set the planner in your configuration files. You'll want to create your own configuration files for configuring the planner at some point anyway.